# What's the right way for summary write to avoid overlapping on tensorboard when restore a model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I wrote a CNN image classifier with tensorflow and use tensorboard to monitor the training. However when I stop and restore from a checkpoint, there are overlaps like:

[image: IMG]

I followed the instruction on the [Tensorboard README](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md) to write a `SessionStatus.START` message to the summary file, but it doesn't seem to work.

---

This is my code:

```
summary_writer.add_session_log(SessionLog(status=SessionLog.START),global_step=step)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i dont know if its an answer, but if you put the global_step variable into a tensorflow variable (to store it with your data) and then, when you restore the model, the global_step variable is also restored to its old value, it will go on from there in tensorboard, or? Sorry,i have not tested it.

Comment: yes, it is right and i solved it. i just restore the model and extra the global_step save as (start_step), after then i immediately add summary_writer.add_session_log(SessionLog(status=SessionLog.START), global_step=start_step), so all the events after this start_step will be discarded and no overlap.