# How to avoid overlapping tensorboard plots after restoring model?

Tags: tensorflow, model, restore, overlap, tensorboard

From: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md

> imagine that TensorFlow wrote a checkpoint at step a, and then continued running until step b, and then crashed and restarted at timestamp a. All of the events written between a and b were "orphaned" by the restart event and should be removed. To facilitate this, we have a SessionLog message in tensorflow/core/util/event.proto which can record SessionStatus.START as an event; like all events, it may have a step associated with it. If TensorBoard detects a SessionStatus.START event with step a, it will assume that every event with a step greater than a was orphaned, and it will discard those events.

Now here's a mock-up of my code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import SessionLog

with tf.Session(config = config) as sess:

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/my_summaries', sess.graph)

    i = 1
    if model_to_restore_exists:
        i = 820 # global step of latest saved model
        saver.restore(sess, '/my_models/model_'+str(i))
        summary_writer.add_session_log(SessionLog(status=SessionLog.START), global_step=i)

    while i < total_steps:
        s = sess.run(merged_summary_op)
        summary_writer.add_summary(s, i)
        _, loss = sess.run([Network.update, Network.loss], feed_dict=input_dict)
        if i % 20 == 0:
            saver.save(sess, '/my_models/model', global_step=i, write_meta_graph=True)
```

The problem is that with this I'm still getting the overlap in the tensorboard (see below). The line `summary_writer.add_session_log(...)` apparently makes no difference. What am I doing wrong?

Additional info:
(1) I have seen the same issue being discussed here: [What's the right way for summary write to avoid overlapping on tensorboard when restore a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636848/whats-the-right-way-for-summary-write-to-avoid-overlapping-on-tensorboard-when) -- Unfortunately, I don't understand much of the solution, possibly due to a language barrier.
(2) I'm still using TF 1.4, but I believe this probably has nothing to do with the issue.

[image: overlapping scalar plots in tensorboard after model restore]

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am facing the same problem. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636848/whats-the-right-way-for-summary-write-to-avoid-overlapping-on-tensorboard-when?rq=1 but that's not working for me.

Comment: i have the same problem here, the scalars written out from previous programme runs are still on the diagrams, i do close my session with session.close() but it's doesn't seem to clear previous programme runs